# Python Convert string to int or float, which one is preferable?

Tags: python, pandas

Sometime I convert string to int and sometime to float,so I would like to know,what is the better?I mean what is the situation that I should choose convert to int or float?

Comment: That depends on the data.  If you expect the number to be in whole units (for example if you're asking the size of someone's family), then use int.  Otherwise if the number would make sense as a fraction (like an amount of money), then use float.

Comment: `float` needs more bytes than `int`. Hence, it consumes more resources to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, you should convert the `str` to a `float` as it is able to handle a more general input, e.g.

```
float("1.2")
>1.2
```

while the conversion attempt to an integer throws a `ValueError`, i.e.

```
int("1.2")
>ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.2'
```

However, it truly depends on the problem at hand. Moreover, you should ask yourself why there is a need to convert a `str` to a number to begin with. Likely, there is a preliminary step in the data pre-processing that might have been mishandled. Converting a string to a number seems more like an attempt to undo a mistake done earlier/by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is "Convert to int unless otherwise is needed."

Integer type is the best one mainly as it has less space. So if you can use integer, use it. If not, use float. (but more memory will be used)

Float is used when you need accurate values.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data you are converting and what you need it for.
If the data is composed of continuous numerical values, then you probably will want to convert to `float`. If the data is made of numerical discreet values, then you're probably ok to use `int`.

[This article may be helpful](https://www.g2.com/articles/discrete-vs-continuous-data)